# How to do special case for empty list when trying to find the maximum increase from one element in the sequence to an element at a higher index?

Tags: python

As the question suggests, I am trying to make a function that returns the largest difference between numbers in a list from one index to a higher index.

e.g. `[1,2,3,2]` returns 2.0

e.g. `[3,2,1,1]` returns 0.0 since it doesn't increase left to right.

My code currently is

```py
def largest_increase(seq):
    minimum = seq[0]
    maximum = 0
    for i in range (len(seq)):
        if (seq[i] < minimum):
            minimum = seq[i]
        elif (seq[i] - minimum > maximum):
            maximum = seq[i] - minimum
        elif len(seq)==0:
            return 0
    return float(maximum)
```

it works for all cases except when I give the empty list. I thought my last `elif` would cover for empty list but clearly not.

Comment: It cannot work with empty list, as the first statement in your function accesses the first item in `seq`. Also note you can just say `for elem in seq` instead of needing to use indices

Comment: Ah I see. How can I alter the statement to work for the empty list as well? Also thanks, I replaced `i` with `elem` :) @EdvardM

Comment: You could do just early  return, eg. `if not seq:    return None`. Also note that sometimes using `math.inf` or `-math.inf` works better without need to have two separate cases (one for None, one for actual value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what @EdvardM is trying to tell you (I am not sure why he did not answer himself).

```
def largest_increase(seq):
    # check for empty seq list right away:
    if len(seq) == 0: # or more simply (and Pythonic): if not seq:
        return 0.0
    minimum = seq[0]
    maximum = 0
    for elem in seq:
        if (elem < minimum):
            minimum = elem
        elif (elem - minimum > maximum):
            maximum = elem - minimum
    return float(maximum)

print(largest_increase([1,2,3,2]))
print(largest_increase([3,2,1,1]))
print(largest_increase([]))
```

Prints:

```
2.0
0.0
0.0
```